# error: subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector Need for class

Tags: c, arrays, matrix

I have to do a program from class and I get that error:

> subscripted value is neither array nor pointer nor vector.

The error is in

```
if((matriz[i][j]>maximo)&&(esta(vector[nvertices-1],i,j,nvertices)==0)){
```

and

```
siguiente=vector[i];
```

I am not quite clear what is the reason behind the error.

CODE:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void camino(int* vector,int matriz,int nvertices);
int esta(int vector,int inicio,int fin,int nvertices);

int main(){

int nvertices;                                                      //numero de vertices
int nconexiones;                                                    //numero de conexiones disponibles
int i,j;                                                            //indices para recorrer la matriz
int conex = 0;                                                      //rectificador de conexiones

printf("Introduce el numero de vertices: ");
scanf("%d",&nvertices);
printf("Introduce el numero de conexiones disponibles: ");
scanf("%d",&nconexiones);
int matad[nvertices][nvertices];                                    //matriz de adyacencia
for(i=1;i<=nvertices;i++){                                          //Rellenar la matriz con ceros, por defecto no hay ninguna conexion
    for(j=1;j<=nvertices;j++){
        matad[i][j]=0;
    }
}

printf("Introduce las capacidades.Si no existe introduce 0:\n");
for(i=1;i<=nvertices;i++){                                          //Introducimos las capacidades
    for(j=1+i;j<=nvertices;j++){
        if(conex<nconexiones){
            printf("Ciudad %d - Ciudad %d: ",i,j);
            scanf("%d",&matad[i][j]);
            matad[j][i]=matad[i][j];
            conex++;
        }
    }
}

int caminos[nvertices-1];                                           //Variable que almacena el camino (como una lista de vertices)
camino(&caminos[nvertices-1],matad[nvertices][nvertices],nvertices);//Llamada a la funcion camino

return 1;
}

void camino(int* vector,int matriz,int nvertices){
int i,j;                                                                            //Indices para recorrer la matriz de adyacencia
for(i=1;i<=nvertices;i++){                                                          //-- Explicacion --
    int maximo = 0;                                                                 //Vamos a empezar por el vertice 1, bucamos el camino de mayor
    for(j=1;j<=nvertices;j++){                                                      //capacidad, una vez lo tenemos comprobamos si esa union 1->X esta
        if((matriz[i][j]>maximo)&&(esta(vector[nvertices-1],i,j,nvertices)==0)){    //o no esta en nuestra lista mediante la funcion    esta(...), si esta
            maximo=j;                                                               //lo añadimos y ahora partimos desde el vertice X -> Y, en caso 
        }                                                                           //contrario hemos acabado.
    }                                                                               //------------------
}                                                                                   //La variable maximo es utilizada para ver que vertice tiene la mayor                                                                   
}                                                                                       //capacidad

int esta(int vector,int inicio,int fin,int nvertices){
int anterior=0;
int siguiente=0;
int encontrado=0;
int i;
for(i=1;i<=nvertices-1;i++){
    anterior=siguiente;
    siguiente=vector[i];
    if((inicio==anterior)&&(fin==siguiente)){
        encontrado=1;
    }
}
return encontrado;
}
```

Comment: Use spaces around binary operators to improve readability and indent your code with four spaces.  Use english names for your variables and functions.

Answer (score 3):

- In your `camino()` function, `matriz` is an `int`.
- In your `esta()` function, `vector` is an `int`, too.

You can use the array indexing operator only on array type variables.

Comment: What would be the solution, what I have to put, I dont know how to do it properly I'm getting starting with C :(

Comment: @Ayala10: Take your favourite C primer, and read on arrays and array subscriptions.